# SQL - How do I create a join with different tables types?

Tags: sql, performance, join

For example I have three tables:

```
Students:
ID, name, address, department, yearEnrolled, etc.

Professors:
ID, name, address, department, etc.

Contractors:
ID, name, address, department, company, etc.

Staff:
ID, name, department, jobClassification, etc.
```

and finally:

```
Parking Spots:
ID, name, location, dataType, dataID, etc.
```

where dataType let's me know if it's a Contractor, Staff, Student, etc., and then the ID is the specific Student, Staff, etc.

This is not in a relationship table because the data is 1:1. One person to one parking spot. ***The tables cannot be changed for reasons outside the scope of this question.***

Basically I have 4 tables that are all for different types of data and one table that links the parking spots to the specific person assigned to them. Hence why the parking spots table includes the dataType.

Now what I want to do is a report that will show a list of all people within the system that have parking spots. So for example I want a report where I get a list of everyone who has a status of current (coded as a number of course):

```
Jane, lot 51, Physics Department [department], Student [dataType], 555-5555
John, lot 52, Chemistry Department [department], Professor [dataType], 555-2212
```

So I guess the question is how do I do a join from multiple different tables for common data from different tables while making the query performant.

Technically I could just join everything and bring back all the data, including a mostly null values, but there must be a better way than joining all the different tables when all I want a list of everyone and just a subset of the common tables (same data types for the columns). Also I imagine this would have terrible performance.

So other than running the query four times, once for each different dataType and then combining them, or running a massive join with tons of null data, do I have any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this using a `UNION`.  Specifically you have 4 queries, each returning the common data.  You could write this up as a view, making it easy to query.

```
 GO

 Create view Combined as
       Select ID, name, address, department, 'students' datatype from Students
Union  Select ID, name, address, department, 'professors' datatype from Professors
Union Select ID, name, address, department, 'contractors' datatype from Contractors
Union Select ID, name, address, department, 'Staff' datatype from Staff 
Go
```

EDIT in response to comment.

You would use it like so...

```
Select Select ID, name, address, department
From Combined c
     Inner join ParkingSpots p
         On c.datatype = p.datatype
```

You could also use a cte like so...

```
;with combined as (
       Select ID, name, address, department, 'students' datatype from Students
Union  Select ID, name, address, department, 'professors' datatype from Professors
Union Select ID, name, address, department, 'contractors' datatype from Contractors
Union Select ID, name, address, department, 'Staff' datatype from Staff 
)
Select Select ID, name, address, department
From Combined c
     Inner join ParkingSpots p
         On c.datatype = p.datatype
```

No need to do the join in either inside the view/union, as the query engine should take care of that for you..

Comment: I love the idea of the View, I just had to go with the other answer since you missed the joins which would be required on each select.

Comment: @StephaneGrenier: you don't need a join inside the view, you do that when using the view.

Answer (score 1):

A union query should work.  This is the general idea.  You can flesh out the details.

```
select blah, blah
from ParkingSpots join Students on something
where dataType = 'Student'
union all
select blah, blah
from ParkingSpots join Professors on something
where dataType = 'Professor'
etc
```